# Is the convertible bond arbitrage strategy really riskless if share price rises a lot?

Tags: stocks, bonds, risk, shorting-securities, arbitrage

Convertible bond arbitrage is a position when one goes short the company's stock and long the company's convertible bond.

I have found many [articles](http://www.eurekahedge.com/NewsAndEvents/News/1381/Convertible-Bond-Arbitrage) on the Internet stating that this is a  riskless strategy  when the stock's price goes up. **But is it really riskless strategy when stock goes very high in a very short time?**

Wouldn't the short fees that grow proportionally with the stock price at one point dwarf any interest received - both from the convertible bond and potential reinvestment of short sale cash into, for example, treasuries?

Answer (score 1):

For most large cap stocks, the borrow fee rate is low and almost negligible (as low as .25%).  So as share price increases, your daily borrow fee debit will increase because share price is rising.

Where the borrow fee becomes problematic is if the underlying is a less liquid stock and the borrow rate starts rocketing up because the stock has become volatile and/or the short interest is increasing and/or the stock  is becoming harder to borrow (my broker shows  83 stocks with borrow rates over 100% !!!).

The delta neutral example in your article is buying two ATM  convertible bonds with a delta of +.50 per 100 short shares of stock (short stock has a delta of -1). This results in a hedge ratio of 1:1.  Delta is non linear and as share price increases so does delta, thereby increasing the hedge ratio (more long bond delta than short stock delta).

To the upside, what you have working against you are the short shares,  the borrow fee, and any premium paid for the bond.

What you have working for you is the increasing hedge ratio.  To a small degree, the arb spread may also be working  in your favor if it is contracting as share price rises (the bond was under valued and/or the shares were overvalued in relation to each other when you opened the position).

If the daily borrow rate isn't climbing significantly while share price is increasing, the increasing borrow fee debt will not be a major factor and it will be more than offset by the increasing hedge ratio.

> The goal of convertible bond arbitrage is to **consistently make money regardless of market conditions** and to do so with **minimal volatility**. The basic mechanics of this market neutral approach is to take simultaneous long and short positions in a convertible bond and its underlying stock. By having the appropriate hedge between long and short positions, the arbitrageur hopes to profit whether the market goes up or down. Despite a focus on absolute returns rather than beating market indices, convertible bond arbitrage strategies have outdone the S&P 500 index with significantly lower volatility over the past decade

While I have no experience with convertible bond arbitrage, I have done a fair amount with stock and options.  The premise isn't different.  The problem that I have with the above statement is that it implies that with delta neutral hedging, one can consistently make money regardless of market conditions.  Succeeding with delta neutral trading requires a lot of hands on rebalancing as well as a cooperative underlying.  If you can acquire some historical data, you can model this and see various outcomes.

Back to the example.  If the underlying drops, you'll gain 100 delta per point drop on the short shares and you'll lose less than 100 delta on the two long convertibles because delta would be shrinking.  However, if  two ATM 50 delta convertibles cost more than the credit received from the short share position, a catastrophic bankruptcy would guarantee a loss.

The short answer? Yes, you can **make money regardless of market conditions** if there is **minimal volatility**.  However, the tails could behave quite differently.  No, the position is not riskless.